# Serializar List JSON em FLutter

Tags: json, serialização, flutter

Tenho uma aplicação em Fluter, e possuo um Json de retorno com List.
Queria serializar a Lista para exibi-la em certo momento, porém não encontrei como fazer isso.
Um exemplo do meu código:

```
class ResultLogin {
 final String token;
 final List<ZLoginResultSchema>schemas;


  ResultLogin({this.token, this.schemas});

  ResultLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    token      = json['token'],
    schemas    = new List.from( json['schemas']);


Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'token':    token,
    'schemas':  schemas,
  };
}
```

Minha Classe ZLoginResultSchema:

```
class ZLoginResultSchema  {
 final String name;
 final String fullname;


 ZLoginResultSchema({this.name, this.fullname});


 ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    name    = json['name'],
    fullname = json['fullname'];


 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'name': name,
    'fullname': fullname,
  };
 }
```

No `ResultLogin.fromJson` o token funciona, porém a lista de schemas não, como serializar uma lista de Json?

Comment: Coloque também o código da sua classe `ZLoginResultSchema`.

Comment: Adicionei o código, desculpe havia esquecido.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que você está tentando mandar o Dart serializar/deserializar uma lista com um objeto personalizado `ZLoginResultSchema`, sem que a linguagem tenha a menor ideia de como fazer isso, afinal esse é um objeto personalizado que você criou. Caso fosse uma lista de `String`, até funcionaria.

Você tem que utilizar o método fromJson da classe `ZLoginResultSchema`para que o Dart entenda como ele deve passar o json para um objeto. Então a classe `ResultLogin` ficaria:

```dart
class ResultLogin {
  final String token;
  final List<ZLoginResultSchema> schemas;

  ResultLogin({this.token, this.schemas});

  factory ResultLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['schemas'] as List;
    List<ZLoginResultSchema> schemas =
        list.map((z) => ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(z));

    return ResultLogin(token: json['token'], schemas: schemas);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'token': token,
        'schemas': schemas,
      };
}
```

Agora note no método fromJson a necessidade de ter que transformar o `Map` do json para uma `List` e converter um a um com o `ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(z)`. Não é nem um pouco prático, certo?

Por isso não é recomendável fazer essa transformação do json de forma manual como você está fazendo. Para isso existem ferramentas como a lib [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) que utiliza o [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) para gerar esses códigos de conversão automática do json, além de ter outras diversas funcionalidades que facilitam e muito nossa vida.

Recomendo que você utilize ela, [para mais detalhes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#use-code-generation-for-medium-to-large-projects).

Answer (score 1):

O seu objeto pode ficar da seguinte forma:

```
class ResultLogin {
 final String token;
 final List<ZLoginResultSchema>schemas;

  ResultLogin({this.token, this.schemas});

  ResultLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    token = json['token'],
    if (json['schemas'] != null) {
     this.schemas = List<ZLoginResultSchema>();
     json['schemas'].forEach((obj) {
      schemas.add(ZLoginResultSchema.fromJson(obj));
     });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
   final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
   data['token'] = this.token;
   data['schemas'] = this.schemas.toJson();
   return data;
  }
}
```

Ao utilizar o ForEach estaremos pegando cada item da lista e convertendo o seu Map para um objeto e depois adicionando-o a lista.
Caso você possua a estrutura do JSON, preferencialmente tendo ele preenchido utilize o [JSON to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).